# Insert values from list into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to insert values from variables and values from a list into a sqlite3 database.

Problem: The list is not unpacked, it is used as a single element. What do I miss? Do I have to unpack the list into variables? In the example `list_element` is a list with six elements

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO websites VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
               ('NULL', qry, strtm, list_element, COUNTER, SPAM, EXCERPT, COLLECTION))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the sequences:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO websites VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
           [None, qry, strtm] + list_element + [COUNTER, SPAM, EXCERPT, COLLECTION])
```

I built a list here as it is easier to concatenate lists and lists than it is to concatenate tuples and lists (you'd have to convert `list_element` to a tuple first).

Note that I used `None` instead of `'NULL'`; `None` is translated to a SQL `NULL` by Python database adapters.